# How to iterate Nested Objects in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am working react on objects to iterate over each and every key and value in react. I have written some code using java script methods. But its not working only, Its displaying only keys when I tried with keys method. But expected out put should be keys and values. Like Key name and its value. name John, and its children name Joe. It should display entire keys and its values.

what I have done explained below.

I have tried to iterate over the objects by using object keys. with same king of methods in java script. Its throwing errors, When I tried with keys its displaying only keys. Finally i tried with entries method but not working. The expected out put should keys and its name display entire object.

```
// react component code

export default function App() {
  const obj = {
    name: "John",
    age: 80,
    children: [
      { name: "Joe", age: 60 },
      {
        name: "Angelena",
        age: 50,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sara",
            age: 30,
            children: [
              { name: "Kiwi", age: 5 },
              { name: "Kuri", age: 7 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { name: "Tena", age: 70 }
    ]
  };
   return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  {obj.name}
  {obj.map(item)=>{
    return (
      <div>{item.[children].name}</div>
    )
  }}
</div>

      );
    }
```

Comment: what kind of object?

Comment: Javascript Object with nested child object.

Comment: add an example of the data structure in the description

Comment: description ? you mean output?

Comment: add an example of input and output

Comment: Input given in the code (obj) and output should be: name : John, age : 80, and its nested objects and follows.

Comment: as a beginner I don't know how to do it with objects. over arrays.

Comment: edit your post and add an example of data as input and the expected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your trying to display all keys and values of  the object you can do the following

```
function renderObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
    <div key={key}>
      {typeof value === "object" ? (
        <div>
          {key}:
          <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>{renderObject(value)}</div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        `${key}: ${value}`
      )}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

heres a  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dew-4k85wh?file=/src/App.js:642-967)

EDIT:
to not show the children key and number of children  and only their name and age update the code to

```
function renderObject(obj, parentKey = "") {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
    <div key={parentKey + key}>
      {parentKey !== "children" && key !== "children" ? (
        <>
          {key}:{" "}
          {typeof value === "object" ? (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>{renderObject(value, key)}</div>
          ) : (
            `${value}`
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>{renderObject(value, key)}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

i updated the codesandbox as well

Comment: I removed `${key}` I am getting children: 0 it should display all objects Name and age not children

Comment: i update the code let me know if this is what your looking for

Comment: Yes i expected the same result Thank you.

Comment: you welcome if my answer solved your question can you please mark it as accepted answer thank you!

Comment: yes i done it, Thanks